# Verificar existência de UK antes de criar uma

Tags: sql, oracle

tenho a seguinte query:

```
alter table FINALIDADE_OPERACAO_MODAL 
        add constraint UK_t127pwh154arjh5whq0g4dlrm unique (NOME);
```

Como crio uma função que verifica se a mesma existe antes, e caso não exista, cria, e se já existir, ele sai do comando.

Answer (score 0):

Sem entrar no mérito da solução

```
declare
    vn_qtd number;
    ...
    begin
      SELECT count(*)
      into vn_qtd
      FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS 
      WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'UK_t127pwh154arjh5whq0g4dlrm';
      if vn_qtd = 0 then
        execute_immediate ('alter table FINALIDADE_OPERACAO_MODAL ' ||
                           ' add constraint UK_t127pwh154arjh5whq0g4dlrm unique (NOME)');
      end if;
end;
```